# Make custom button on Tab Bar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image]

the screenshot is taken from an earlier version of iOS Device.

[image]

Image Set From `Main.storyborad`:

[image]

1. Why show the center button background clear ?
2. How to show a center button with the background color ?
3. How to set all button in Vertical alignment ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to assets select image > Attribute inspector > render as > show original image

[image]